# How to align particles

Tags: particles

I have a mesh street and i want to align the lamp on the street. Some or few are align and almost all the lamp are distributed here and there. I have added the particles as a street lamp.

[image]

I have made the street with the OSM addon. Any help or suggestion to align the street light.

[image]